# Python and Excel file running together

Tags: python, windows, excel, pyqt4

I have already create a Python application which has a graphic user interface. 
It has some buttons. One of them launch an Excel file. The problem is that meanwhile the Excel file is open the GUI crashes.

I´d like to mantain both application open my GUI made in Pyhton and the excel file where the user make some calculation for the scripts included in the GUI

The button:

```
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButtonxxxx_SpreadSheet, QtCore.SIGNAL ('clicked()') ,self.launch_xxxxpreadSheet)
```

the script who launch the excel file:

```
def launch_xxxxSpreadSheet(self):
    os.system('example.xlsm')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run os.system it launches the program in the same thread, so the rest of your program will not continue running. You could use os.startfile on Windows to run it separately, thus not stopping the thread.

Comment: It runs perfectly. Thanks